# Not getting output of bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields, bitflags

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test
{
    unsigned int x;
    long int y: 33;
    unsigned int z;
};
int main()
{
    struct test t;
    printf("%d",sizeof(t));
    return 0;
}
```

output

24

size of long int is 8 byte but here it is taking 16 byte why?

Comment: See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Try using `__attribute__((packed))`

Comment: so can you tell me what is the size of 'y' variable here..